# Drupal 8.6 Unable to theme a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I'm new to D8. I want to customise the theme of a view. I have already created a block view and assigned into the sidebar of bartik's theme (default provided). See the below screen shot.
[image]

Now, I've made the twig debug as true and saw the theming guide for the view files:

```
<!-- FILE NAME SUGGESTIONS:
   * block--views-block--articles-block-1.html.twig
   * block--views-block--articles-block-1.html.twig
   * block--views-block.html.twig
   * block--views.html.twig
   x block.html.twig
-->
```

Now, I have created a file named "`block--views-block--articles-block-1.html.twig`" within the path: "`/themes/bartik/templates/views/`" and wrote something like:

```
Hello

{% for row in rows %}
test
{% endfor %}
```

After clearing cache, I see there is no change in the view theme and it renders as default. 
[image]

What did I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating block template that contains block title and content, not a views template.

The view template name should start by "views--".

Comment: Can you please write the complete file name?

Comment: Why the view theme file suggestion won't provide me these details?

Comment: Should I create file name like: `views-view--articles--block-1.html.twig` ?

Comment: Example: views--articles.html.twig or views--articles--block-1.html.twig

Comment: Renamed the file name as you suggested and cleared cache. Nothing happen.

Answer (score 0):

@niladri, You have chosen format to unformmated.I will suggest to create template in views directory in your theme. `Views-view-unformatted--[view machine name]--[view display name].html.twig`
Clear cache after this via drush or Drupal 
`admin/config/development/performance`.